# How to fix Error CS1738 Named argument specifications must appear after all fixed arguments have been specified?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm stuck with an error: CS1738: Named argument specifications must appear after all fixed arguments have been specified. Please use language version 7.2 or greater to allow non-trailing named arguments.

can you help, please?

```
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
@Html.LabelFor(expression: model => model.SubjectId)
@Html.DropDownListFor(expression: model => model.SubjectId, Model.ListOfSubject,htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @id = "txtTotalMarks" })</div> //error
div class="form-group col-md-4">
```

I follow the instructions in the video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9SSz_m2-2sQ

Comment: Do you understand what the error message is telling you? Do you know what a named argument is? You could either corect the call (e.g. remove  `expression:`) or upgrade to a C# version >= 7.2

Comment: @KlausGütter omg thank you so much!!! just deleted expression

Answer (score 0):

A "named argument", as the name implies, is when you specify the name of the argument with a colon before the value.

Arguments that are not named are called "fixed arguments" or "positional arguments", because the order (position) they are in determines which argument is which.

**For example**:
`FooBar(argu1: val1, argu2: val2)` calls the `FooBar` method with the `argu1` and  `argu2` arguments *named* explicitly.
Calling it without naming either argument would look like `FooBar(val1, val2)`.

In versions of C# before version 7.2, you cannot specify any *named* arguments before *positional* arguments.

In your code:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    expression: model => model.SubjectId,   // named argument
    Model.ListOfSubject,                    // positional argument
    htmlAttributes: new { ... })            // named argument
```

you specified the `expression` argument with a name, *before* the `selectList` argument, which you specified without a name.

You need to either specify all arguments by name:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    expression: model => model.SubjectId,
    selectList: Model.ListOfSubject,
    htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @id = "txtTotalMarks" })
```

Or remove the name `expression:` from the first argument:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    model => model.SubjectId,
    Model.ListOfSubject,
    htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @id = "txtTotalMarks" })
```

Or just specify all arguments by position:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    model => model.SubjectId,
    Model.ListOfSubject,
    new { @class = "form-control", @id = "txtTotalMarks" })
```